# Why is this the same even when object pointers differ in multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, multiple-inheritance

When using multiple inheritance C++ has to maintain several vtables which leads to having "several views" of common base classes.

Here's a code snippet:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

void dumpPointer( void* pointer )
{
    __int64 thisPointer = reinterpret_cast<__int64>( pointer );
    char buffer[100];
   _i64toa( thisPointer, buffer, 10 );
    OutputDebugStringA( buffer );
    OutputDebugStringA( "\n" );
}

class ICommonBase {
public:
    virtual void Common() = 0 {}
};

class IDerived1 : public ICommonBase {
};

class IDerived2 : public ICommonBase {
};

class CClass : public IDerived1, public IDerived2 {
public:
    virtual void Common() {
        dumpPointer( this );
    }
    int stuff;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CClass* object = new CClass();
    object->Common();
    ICommonBase* casted1 = static_cast<ICommonBase*>( static_cast<IDerived1*>( object ) );
    casted1->Common();
    dumpPointer( casted1 );

    ICommonBase* casted2 = static_cast<ICommonBase*>( static_cast<IDerived2*>( object ) );
    casted2->Common();
    dumpPointer( casted2 );

    return 0;
}
```

it produces the following output:

```
206968 //CClass::Common this
206968 //(ICommonBase)IDerived1::Common this
206968 //(ICommonBase)IDerived1* casted1
206968 //(ICommonBase)IDerived2::Common this
206972 //(ICommonBase)IDerived2* casted2
```

here `casted1` and `casted2` have different values which is reasonable since they point to different subobjects. At the point when the virtual function is called the cast to the base class has been done and the compiler doesn't know that it was a most derived class originally. Still *this* is the same each time. How does it happen?

Comment: Why does it matter. That is an implementation detail that is not relevant to any C++ code. The only time you need to know this detail is if you are writing the compiler. In-fact I would not bet the detail would stay the same across compilers.

Comment: @Martin I agree with your sentiment, however, the issue the compiler faces here is an interesting one that's worthy of attention, and even occasionally has real-world consequences, for example to be aware of so you don't write code that assumes the cast will work a certain way.

Comment: I should not that since you use a diamond inheritance without virtual inheritance... there are probably 2 occurences of 'Common' in the vtable of `CClass` so I don't really know how this influence your test...

Comment: @asveikau: No, if it is relevant to your real-world code, then your real-world code is wrong. You *shouldn't* assume that it will work a certain way, past the guarantees given by the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When multiple inheritance is used in a virtual function call, the call to the virtual function will often go to a 'thunk' that adjusts the `this` pointer.  In  your example, the `casted1` pointer's vtbl entry doesn't need a thunk becuase the `IDerived1` sub-object of the `CClass` happens to coincide with the start of the CClass object (which is why the `casted1` pointer value is the same as the `CClass` `object` pointer).

However, the `casted2` pointer to the `IDerived2` sub-object doesn't coincide with the start of the `CClass` object, so the vtbl function pointer actually points to a thunk instead of directly to the `CClass::Common()` function.  The thunk adjusts the `this` pointer to point to the actual `CClass` object then jumps to the `CClass::Common()` function.  So it will  always get a pointer to the start of the `CClass` object, regardless of which type of sub-object pointer it might have been called from.

There's a very good explanation of this in S[tanley Lippman's "Inside the C++ Object Model" book](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0201834545), section 4.2 "Virtual Member Functions/Virtual Functions Under MI".

Comment: As an aside - this is one possible implementation of virtual functions with MI, but it's a common one, and the one apparently used by MSVC.  However, even if this particular implementation isn't specified by the standard, it's still useful to know how this type of operation might work.

Comment: @Michael, I understand the description generic enough not to collide with any possible implementation. Pointers into subobjects will not match, and before calling the virtual method the system must adapt the `this` pointer so that when passed into the method it does refer to the beginning of the (sub)object where that method is implemented. How this is done, and what would the 'thunk' look like are implementation defined. (Also I upvoted for the idea, I don't think that the vtable points to the thunk, but rather has info so that the pointer can be adjusted by the compiler at the place of call.

Comment: `this` is traditionally passed as the first (hidden) parameter to a method call bound to an object. So it's more like the method of the vtable is passed the 'thunk' > there is only one vtable for all instances of the same classes so doing otherwise would be playing with fire in Multi Threaded environments.

Comment: @dribeas - having an adjustment in the vtbl entry is another way this can be implemented (and according to Lippman is how cfront did it), but it's not how MSVC does it (or IAR's compiler). If you think about it, a vtbl pointing to a thunk is logically equivalent to a vtbl with an adjustment offset in it. The 'thunk' variant has the advantage that there's no overhead for the common case of no adjustment necessary (the thunk is a no-op, so the vtbl can point to the actual function). Cfront used used adjustment offsets in the vtbl because it's difficult to implement thunks in C.

Comment: @Matthieu - there's nothing that says a class must have only one vtbl instance. But in the common case of single inheritance there's no reason to have multiple copies.  There's no need to update vtbl's - they can be statically initialized at program start (they can be in ROM), so there is no issue with multi-threading. In this scheme a plain-old `IDerived2` object will point to one vtbl, and a `IDerived2` object that's a super-class (or sub-object) of a `CClass` will point to a different vtbl.

Answer (score 3):

When casted to a different type, the offsets of fields as well as entries in the vtable have to be in a consistent place.  Code that takes an `ICommonBase*` as a parameter doesn't know that your object is really an `IDerived2`.  Yet it still should be able to dereference `->foo` or call the virtual method `bar()`.  If these aren't at predictable addresses that has no way of working.

For the single inheritance case, this is easy to get right.  If `Derived` inherits from `Base`, you can just say that offset 0 of `Derived` is also offset 0 of `Base`, and the members unique to `Derived` can go after the last member of `Base`.   For multiple inheritance obviously that can't work because the first byte of `Base1` can't also be the first byte of `Base2`.  Each one needs its own space.

So if you had such a class that inherits from two (call it `Foo`), the compiler can know that for the type `Foo`, the `Base1` part starts at offset X, and the `Base2` part starts at offset Y.  When casting to either type, the compiler can just add the appropriate offset to `this`.

When an actual virtual method of `Foo` is called, where the implementation is provided by `Foo`, it still needs the "real" pointer to the object, so that it can access all of its members, not just the particular instance of the base `Base1` or `Base2`.  Hence `this` still needs to point to the "real" object.

Note that the implementation details of this may be different than described, this is just a high level description of why the problem exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the object layout in memory for this it will be something like this:

```
v-pointer for IDerived1
v-pointer for IDerived2
....
....
```

It can be otherway also..but just to give an idea..

Your `this` will always point to the start of the object i.e. where the v-pointer for IDerived1 is stored. However, when you cast the pointer to `IDetived2` the casted pointer will be pointing to the v-pointer for `IDerived2` which will be offset by sizeof(pointer) from `this` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

There's the same object model in G++ 4.3 as shown by you, (see answer of Naveen) say casted1 and casted2 have different values.

Furthermore, in G++ 4.3, even you use brutal casting:

```
ICommonBase* casted1 = (ICommonBase*)(IDerived1*)object; 
ICommonBase* casted2 = (ICommonBase*)(IDerived2*)object;
```

the result is the same.

Very clever the compiler

Comment: Not really "brutal" casting, they're `static_cast`s. Try `reinterpret_cast` if you want to see it fail.