# Is using implicit conversion for an upcast instead of QueryInterface() legal with multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, com, multiple-inheritance

Assume I have a class implementing two or more COM interfaces (exactly as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742848/why-exactly-do-i-need-an-explicit-upcast-when-implementing-queryinterface-in-an)):

```
class CMyClass : public IInterface1, public IInterface2 { 
};
```

`QueryInterface()` must return the same pointer for each request of the same interface (it needs an explicit upcast for proper pointer adjustment):

```
if( iid == __uuidof( IUnknown ) ) { 
    *ppv = static_cast<IInterface1*>( this );
    //call Addref(), return S_OK 
} else if( iid == __uuidof( IInterface1 ) ) {
    *ppv = static_cast<IInterface1*>( this );
    //call Addref(), return S_OK 
} else if( iid == __uuidof( IInterface2 ) ) {
    *ppv = static_cast<IInterface2*>( this );
    //call Addref(), return S_OK 
} else {
    *ppv = 0;
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}
```

now there're two `IUnknown`s in the object - one is the base of `IInterface1` and the other is the base of `IInterface2`. And [they are in different subobjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747220/why-is-this-the-same-even-when-object-pointers-differ-in-multiple-inheritance).

Let's pretend I called `QueryInterface()` for `IInterface2` - the pointer returned will be different from the pointer returned when I call `QueryInterface()` for `IUnknown`. So far so good. Then I can pass the retrieved `IInterface2*` into any function accepting `IUnknown*` and thanks to C++ implicit conversion the pointer will be accepted, but it will be not the same pointer that `QueryInterface()` for `IUnknown*` would retrieve. In fact if that function calls `QueryInterface()` for `IUnknown` immediately upon being called it will retrieve a different pointer.

Is this legal in terms of COM? How do I handle situations when I have a pointer to a multiply-inherited object and I allow an implicit upcast?

Comment: Practically speaking, I've never seen any code make use of COM Identity rules. That said, the other IUnknown* is NOT legal - you MUST choose one to return from QueryInterface.

In terms of your own, internal, C++ use of the COM object implementing object - if you are casting you arn't doing COM anyway, so anything you're doing is legal C++, but not legitimage COM.

Comment: @Chris Becke: I guess identity is required to implement some cache-like functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM has no rules regarding interface identity, only of object identity.  The first rule of QI says that a QI on IID_Unknown on two interface pointers must return the same pointer if they are implemented by the same *object*.  Your QI implementation does this correctly.

Without a guarantee for interface identity, a COM method cannot assume that it gets the same IUnknown pointer passed that it will retrieve when it calls QI on that pointer.  So if object identity needs to be proven then a separate QI is required.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there are a small misunderstanding. Interfaces `IInterface1` and `IInterface2` are pur abstract. There are no separate `QueryInterface()` for `IInterface1` and `IInterface2`. There are only a declaration, that class `CMyClass` will implement all methods from `IInterface1` and `IInterface2` (the set of methods of `CMyClass` is the set of methods `IInterface1` and `IInterface1` together).

So you implement in the class `CMyClass` **one** `QueryInterface()`, **one** `AddRef()` and **one** `Release()` method. In the `QueryInterface()` you cast the pointer to instance of class `CMyClass` to `static_cast<IUnknown*>`.

**UPDATED**: Hi! I had to drive away immediately after writing my answer. Only now I could read all other answers and can add something to my answer.

OK. You say that if you cast `IInterface1` to `IUnknown` and if you cast `IInterface2` to `IUnknown` you receive two different pointers. You are right! But nevertheless it does not matter. If you compare **the contains of both pointers** (which addresses has `QueryInterface()`, `AddRef()` and `Release()` in both cases) you will see that both pointer has the same contain. So I am also right!

There are a lot of good examples how to implement COM in pure C. In this case you need define a static structs with pointers to the virtual functions like `QueryInterface()`, `AddRef()` and `Release()` and give the pointer of such struct back as a result of `QueryInterface()`. It shows one more time, that only the contain which you gives back is important for COM and not a pointer (it is not important which vtable you give back).

One more small remark. In some comments you write about the possibility to have many implementations of methods `QueryInterface()`, `AddRef()` and `Release()`. I disagree here. The reason is that **interfaces are pure abstract classes** and if you define a class which implement some interfaces you have no typical class inheritance. You have only **one class with one implementation of all functions from all interfaces**. If you do this in C++, then compiler create and fill static vtables with the corresponding pointers to the only implementation of the functions `QueryInterface()`, `AddRef()`, `Release()` and so on, but all vtables points to the same functions.

To reduce of the number of vtables Microsoft introduced `__declspec(novtable)` or `ATL_NO_VTABLE`, but it is not the part of your questions.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But there's a formal problem. When I implicitly upcast from `IInterface2` to `IUnknown` I get a pointer different from the one I get from `QI()`. The whole questionn is about one thing: is that `IUnknown` "legal" in terms of COM?

Comment: There are many implementations of these methods, even if all but one forward the call to the single version that implements it.

Answer (score 2):

As [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184030/is-using-implicit-conversion-for-an-upcast-instead-of-queryinterface-legal-with/3184348#3184348) points out, your implementation of `QueryInterface` is correct.

It is the responsibility of the *user* of a COM object to use `QueryInterface` at all times. The reason is exactly to prevent the scenario you have pointed out: that casting an IInterface1* or IInterface2* pointer to the IUnknown* pointer will yield different physical values.

In C++, it is not possible for the *implementer* to prevent the user from doing wrong.

Whether it will cause failure in an application depends on whether the application ***cares*** about comparing COM objects for identity.

[MSDN: The Rules of the Component Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810016.aspx)

> **Object identity.** It is required that
>   any call to **QueryInterface** on any
>   interface for a given object instance
>   for the specific interface **IUnknown**
>   must always return the same physical
>   pointer value. This enables calling
>   **QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, ...)** on
>   any two interfaces and comparing the
>   results to determine whether they
>   point to the same instance of an
>   object (the same COM object identity).

As [Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184030/is-using-implicit-conversion-for-an-upcast-instead-of-queryinterface-legal-with/3184180#3184180) points out, the failure of object identity will have a rather limited effect, because the calling of COM interface members is essentially unaffected - each virtual table entry will point to the same function address if the function signature matches.

All COM smart pointer implementations use `QueryInterface` when casting to a different interface, or when the current interface is dubious. Their comparison operators automatically use `QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, ...)` on each input pointer in order to get physical IUnknown* pointers which can be directly compared. The failure of object identity will start to affect your application if you opt to use raw pointers throughout your application.

One special case where the failure will not manifest is when the class does not have any diamond inheritance. However, implicit casting is always illegal in COM, regardless of whether it crashes an application or not.

Comment: I've read The Rules, but... They say that `QueryInterface()`, not anything else, must follow the identity requirement. How does that really mean that an implicit upcast is illegal? `QI()` is `QI()`, C++ conversions are C++ conversions.

Comment: I disagree.  The quote talks about *object identity*, not the same thing as interface identity.

Comment: @sharptooth: When thinking in COM, try to stay away from the thinking that IInterface1 inherits from IUnknown. A more precise way is to say: IInterface1 contains the members AddRef, Release and QueryInterface as well as its own functions.

Comment: @Hans: I admit that there may be a confusion. The title of this question says "implicit conversion for an upcast instead of QueryInterface". Inside the question @sharptooth asks if it is illegal to *allow* this to happen. (I'll edit my answer to clarify)

Comment: Anyway the rule says that two QI calls for the same interface on the same object must return the same pointer. This requirement is not violated with an upcast - QI will still work fine.

Comment: @Hans: I deleted my old comment because I did not clearly say which side (QI implementer or the COM user) should/should not use C++ casting. I edited my answer again to say that @sharptooth's QI is correct.

Comment: I realize my assertion was too strict. I found that even in official code, it is allowed to cast to IUnknown. The burden of removing the IUnknown ambiguity falls onto the function which compares object identity. For this reason, the comparison function will always call QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown) even if you are passing in an IUnknown.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `interface IInterface1 : IDispatch` and `interface IInterface2 : IDispatch` then `QI` for `IUnknown` on `IInterface1` and `IInterface2` must  return the same pointer per object identity rule

but...

`QI` for `IDispatch` on `IInterface1` can return a different implementation compared to `QI` for `IDispatch` on `IInterface2`.

So the answer is (again) **it depends**. Negative for upcasting to `IUnknown`, could be positive for upcasting to anything else.